# database user having grants to same table in 2 schemas

Tags: oracle

I tried the following - and was expecting an error but it seems to work
User1 is given select grants to table XYZ which is present in two schemas
test1.XYZ and test2.XYZ

Now this user - User1 is given 'SELECT' grants to the table XYZ present in both schemas - test1 and test2

I was expecting that the following select would give an exception of something like 'ambiguous' etc etc - but it worked: ( logged in as User1 )

```
select * from XYZ;
```

It seemed to get the details from XYZ table in schema test1.
Kind of confused why this would work.

Comment: Please login again as user1, and run `SELECT owner, table_name FROM ALL_TABLES where table_name = 'XYZ'`, and please append a result of this query to the question. This query shows all tables with name `XYZ` visible to User1.

Comment: Is there any synonym created for `XYZ` anywhere?

Comment: sorry my bad I did have a synonym for XYZ of test1 :( my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that does not exist a table with that name in your schema, it probably depends on synonyms;
for example, create tables with same name in different schemas

```
SQL> conn test1/test1@main
Connected.
SQL> create table xyz(id number);

Table created.

SQL> grant select on xyz to user1;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn test2/test2@yourDB
Connected.
SQL> create table xyz(id number);

Table created.

SQL> grant select on xyz to user1;

Grant succeeded.
```

This way your user will have no doubt, but will not see any of the tables:

```
SQL> conn user1/user1@yourDB
Connected.
SQL> select * from xyz;
select * from xyz
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

If you add the schema, you can query:

```
SQL> select * from test1.xyz;

no rows selected

SQL> select * from test2.xyz;

no rows selected
```

Now you create a public synonym for one of your tables:

```
SQL> conn test1/test1@yourDB
Connected.
SQL> create public synonym xyz for xyz;

Synonym created.
```

This way your user will see only the table with the synonym:

```
SQL> conn user1/user1@yourDB
Connected.
SQL> select * from xyz;

no rows selected
```

Even after creating synonym, you can access tables by writing 'schema.table'.

Comment: Thanks for the details - it was my bad - I had a synonym created - though I dont remember when I did it - but yes - your example above is correct - thank you